# Could not find a declaration file for module 'cloudinary' after cloudinary dependancy npm install

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I have installed Cloudinary sdk in my project but when trying to create a variable from the sdk I get the following error -

[image]

the thing is that I already have installed the cloudinary sdk in my project, it is inside my "node_modules" inside functions

[image]

it is for sure something that I am missing in the directory path that the IDE can't recognise, but I can't figure out what.

UPDATE:
Here is my list of project dependencies from `package.json`:

```
"@google-cloud/pubsub": "^0.17.0",
"aws-sdk": "^2.526.0",
"cloudinary": "^1.15.0",
"ffmpeg-static": "^2.0.0",
"firebase-admin": "^8.5.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.2.0",
"fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
"secure-compare": "^3.0.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. I consults out of 2 things -

1) I have made a mistake that when I have pointed to the variables created out of the cloudinary variables I re-referenced the "v2" variable, which is not necessary as I already declared the variable with "v2".

2) Visual studio code IDE is just...bad (to say the least). Even-tough everything is working right now, the error "could not find a file declaration..." persist. I have no explanation for this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Cloudinary doesn't support TS. If you want to use Node.js try `npm install cloudinary`.
you can follow this on Cloudinary's node.js GitHub repo- https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/issues/175

Update: Cloudinary added support for TS.

Comment: as far as I know I am not using TS. I am using node JS 8. I have done the 'npc install cloudinary' command, the sdk has been installed to my project, but I can't seem to reference a variable out of a require from my cloudinary sdk. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error you are getting indicates that you have a TypeScript code in your server. Maybe check your `package.json` if any package there includes TS code.

Comment: Can you please specify what indicates that I am using TS? I have opened a new clean Node JS server that has nothing inside it but it still does not work, meaning that the initial setup necessary for setup a new server makes it impossible for implementing cloudinary SDK?

Comment: I checked my dependencies, I don't have any dependency that seems like a TypeScript. Please see the list of dependencies I am using on my project (I have updated my post)

Comment: I have also tried creating a BRAND NEW project with `cloudinary` as the ONLY dependency and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You can use the branch referred to in the last comment in the GitHub: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/issues/175. This branch should work for you.